# How to run an ANOVA on specific variables in R using a CSV?

Tags: r, csv

I am new to R and currently I am working with participant data in which I want to run ANOVA's on each category.

I have read my data from my CSV using the following line of code:

```
CSV <- read.csv("data.csv", header=TRUE)
```

The vector CSV now is a lot of obs. of 12 variables. The last variable depicts the group, where as the first 11 variables are each category. I wish to run ANOVAs by separating the data into groups based on the value of the 12th variable and run an ANOVA for each variable 2 - 11.

How would I separate the data into N groups based on the 12th variable and run an ANOVA for each variable 2 - 11?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read in the file:

```
CSV <- read.csv("data.csv", header=TRUE)
```

Set the index for 12, the upper bound, and lower bound for use of iterating through the categories:

```
lenCSV <- 12
upper <- 11
lower <- 2
```

Iterate through the categories and output the summary:

```
for( j in lower:upper) {
  fm <- as.formula(paste(names(CSV[j])," ~", names(lenCSV)))

  fit<-aov(fm,data=CSV)
  print(fit)
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. Code-only answers are sometimes good enough, but code+explanation answers are always better

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused as to what you mean by ANOVA for each variable. Below is a loop that runs through each value of your 12th variable, subsets the data, and then runs ANOVA. You need to change the "y ~ x" part since I don't know what your dependent/independent variables will be. If you want to run ANOVA for each variable on each other variable, you might require another loop which i tried below.

```
for(i in unique(CSV[,12])) {
    data<-subset(CSV, subset=CSV[,12]==i)
    fit <- aov(y ~ x, data=data)
    fit
}
```

## for each variable

```
`%ni%`<-Negate(`%in%`) ##setting up 'not in'

for(i in unique(CSV[,12])) {
    data<-subset(CSV, subset=CSV[,12]==i)

    for( j in 1:11) {
       fm <- as.formula(paste(names(data[,j])," ~", paste(names(data)[names(data) %ni%  names(data[,j])], collapse = "+")))

       fit<-aov(fm,data=data)
       fit #you may want to output the results rather than printing them here
    }
}
```

Comment: Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
  incompatible dimensions

Comment: The above is the error I get when I run the code, currently debugging it.